# Application.SendKeys "({1068})" doesnt work together with Application.OnTime

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I'm  trying to get a macro on a schedule through Application.OnTime as below (located in ThisWorkbook):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()        
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:50:02"), "CopyScreen"                 
End Sub
```

Whereas the "CopyScreen" sub is as below (located in regular module):

```
Sub CopyScreen()

Application.SendKeys "({1068})", True          
DoEvents             
ActiveSheet.Paste             
End Sub
```

The CopyScreen() module works fine when calling it from a manual prompt (F5), but whenever calling it through the scheduled Workbook_Open() sub, a black screenshot gets copied. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code:

```
Sub CopyScreen()

  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = ActiveSheet
  
  Application.SendKeys "({1068})", True
  DoEvents
  With sht
      .Activate
      .Paste
  End With 'sht
```

Apparently, Excel forgets ActiveSheet when it goes to sleep waiting for the set time. Go figure!

HTH

End Sub

Comment: Hmm, still no change for me. Is there any other way to capture a screenshot other than SendKeys (which can be flaky as is)?